# Collection of PNaCl ports with compiled .pexe files (Ex: ImageMagick)?

Tags: imagemagick, google-nativeclient

The list of current NaCl ports is here: https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList

I'm curious if there is (or will be) a repository for PNaCl executables (.pexe files) since they only need a .nmf manifest wrapper to run?

Please list any PNaCl resources here, I'm looking for ImageMagick specifically.

I know I could probably build the .pexe myself but I don't have the time to learn Native Client.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: this isn't available yet, but we are working on it.

The long answer:

There isn't currently a binary repository for naclports. We are planning to add that soon (likely this quarter).

I took a quick look at the ImageMagick port, and it looks like it currently only generates libraries, not an application binary (i.e. nexe/pexe). My guess is that it wouldn't be too hard to add this, however.

Even with a pexe, you'll need to have a way to launch the application, give it commandline options, and a set of files to process. I've discussed a way to do this with my team, but we haven't started work on it yet (though again, we'll likely work on this in Q1 2014).

Comment: Hi, I have question of similar nature, but about compiled shared libraries, rather than executables: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21804072/544721 . Anyway, looking forward on updates (btw. Have you considered, some board with "currently working on" a kinf of status dashboard, no necessarily providing any eta? :) )