# Native Client application vs shared libraries (e.g.security) updates?

Tags: security, shared-libraries, google-nativeclient

In traditional model, when program does dynamic linking of shared library, than - as one of side effects - it, usually does not have to care about updates, as when new version (let's say with security or performance fix) comes, it's updated (by some kind of package manager on some Uhix or sth equivalent on Windows), and application can benefit on next run from new version.
In such process, application maintainer does not have to perform any steps, in order for his/her users to benefit from new , fixed library.

How does it work in Native Client?
Are those libraries packed in package, so developer has to repackage every time new version of library comes,
or is there some mechanism, either to benefit from some way or sharing libraries, or getting this package repacked automatically (for example by Chrome Web Store) ?

I've eye-balled:

- [Distributing Your Application](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/distributing)
- [Building](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/devcycle/building)
- [Application Structure](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/coding/application-structure)

and couldn't find answer. (It does not mean it's not there, I could miss sth).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with NaCl, your app is responsible for updating any libraries it depends on, as those libraries are necessarily distributed with your NaCl application. The exception would be any libraries/APIs that the browser provides to the application, which would be updated along with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, there night be a way of structuring application, so app can download new shared libraries via some bootstrap executable and than run, desired one with freshly downloaded shared libraries:

- http://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/dynamic-loading (please note

that it's different page than [this one earlier mentioned](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/devcycle/dynamic-loading) )
search for "libreverse.so" example.

Anyhow, if you have better structured answer and/or more detailed, please let know.